# Nullhomotopy of a chain map

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra, homological-algebra

Let $(C, \partial), (C',\partial')$ be two chain complexes, and $f: C \rightarrow C'$ be a chain map. In general we know that if $f$ is zero-homotopic (i.e.  $\exists$ a collection of maps $s_k: C_k \rightarrow C_{k+1}'$ with $f_k = \partial' s_{k} + s_{k-1}\partial$), then $f$ induces the zero map on homology. I think the converse is in general false. But I was able to prove the following:

> If $C$ is a free complex, $C'$ is exact and both complexes are zero in degree $< 0$, then every chain map which induces the zero map on homology is in fact zero-homotopic.

**Proof** We construct the $s_k$ inductively. First let $k=0$. Because $C'$ is exact and $C'_{-1} = 0$ we know that $\partial_1: C'_1 \rightarrow C'_0$ is surjective. If $\{b_i\}$ is a basis of $C_0$, we may just choose preimages $c_i \in C_1'$ for each $f(b_i)$, and define $s_0(b_i) := c_i$.

Now let $k > 0$ and suppose for $j < k$ we already have defined $s_j$. To define $s_k$, consider the map $g := f_k - \partial_k' s_{k-1}$. To choose preimages of $g(b_i)$ we need to show that $g(C_k) \subset \text{im}(\partial'_{k+1}) = \text{ker}(\partial'_k)$. But

\begin{align}
\partial'_k g &= \partial_k' f - \partial_k' s_{k-1} \partial_k = \partial'_kf - \partial'_k s_{k-1} \partial_{k} \\ &= \partial'_kf - (f_{k-1} - s_{k-2}\partial_{k-1})\partial_k \\&= \partial'_kf_k - f_{k-1} \partial_{k} = 0
\end{align}

My questions are:

1. Is my reasoning correct?
2. Can some of the hypothesis be weakened?

Comment: If $C'$ is exact, then its homology is zero so you can remove the "$f$ induces zero in homology" assumption. But also, you can go from "free" to "projective" quite easily.

Comment: Note that for vector spaces (or actually more generally semi-simple rings, e.g. sufficiently nice group rings on fields) you can remove the exactness condition on $C'$ and replace it with the assumption that $f$ induces $0$ on homology.